# jquery: append text and object results in [object Object]

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to dynamically place a button element next to some text but I'm getting the following in the DOM: `Text next to button [object Object]`.

```js
$btn = $('<button>').text('Button');
$('<div>').html('Text next to button ' + $btn).appendTo($('#test'))
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p43rft4q/1/

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix this?

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Check the jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to append the text and then the element.  You were appending an object to text, which is why you were getting the [Object object].

```js
$btn = $('<button>').text('Button');
$('<div>').append('Text next to button ').append($btn).appendTo($('#test'))
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```
$btn = $('<button>').text('Button');
$('<div>').html('Text next to button ' + $btn[0].outerHTML).appendTo($('#test'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$btn = $('<button>').text('Button');
$('<div>').html('Text next to button ' + $btn.clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html()).appendTo($('#test'))
```

Basically what this is doing is creating a "clone" of the element, then wrapping the clone in a div, switching to the div (parent) then grabbing the html contents of that parent div.